# Javascript: Setting class property from ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "class"/function called Spotlight. I'm trying to retrieve some information through ajax and assign it to a property of Spotlight. Here is my Spotlight class:

```
function Spotlight (mId,mName) {
    this.area = new Array();

    /**
     * Get all area information
     */
    this.getArea = function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: base_url +'spotlight/aGetArea',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                this.area = data;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have assigned the object to an array, and it would be difficult to get to it from within Spotlight, so I'm hoping to access everything using 'this.' It appears though that the success function is outside of the class, and I don't know how to make it inside the class.

Is there a way to get the data into the class property using this.area rather than Spotlight.area?

Comment: I think you want to get the data from your ajax request and use it elsewhere in your class? Defined a new function, lets say newFun(newData) and then in your success function call, newFun(data). Is that what you want to do?

Comment: That may also work. I ended up using the context option in $.ajax.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The value of this is dependent on how each function is called. I see 3 ways around this problem:

#### 1. Creating an alias to this

```
var that = this;
this.getArea = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url +'spotlight/aGetArea',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            that.area = data;
        }
    });
};
```

#### 2. Using jQuery `.ajax` `context` option

```
this.getArea = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url +'spotlight/aGetArea',
        type: 'POST',
        context : this,
        success: function (data) {
            this.area = data;
        }
    });
};
```

#### 3. Using a bound function as the callback

```
this.getAreaSuccess = function (data) {
    this.area = data;
};
this.getArea = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url +'spotlight/aGetArea',
        type: 'POST',
        success: this.getAreaSuccess.bind(this)
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I checked the first one and second one and they both work. I am using the second one.

Comment: Great! You chose the "official" jQuery way.

Answer (score 4):

Well `Spotlight.area` wouldn't work anyway. You just need to preserve the outer `this`:

```
this.area = [];
var theSpotlight = this;
```

and then in the callback:

```
  theSpotlight.area = data;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, it worked, but I find bfavaretto's solution to be more in depth, and the .ajax context option seems cleaner to me. I've 'up' voted your answer though.

Comment: @Samir note that in his `.bind()` example you could also use a local function inside "getArea" in case you don't want "getAreaSuccess" to be exposed on the objects. (Being exposed isn't necessarily a problem of course.)

Answer (score 1):

When inside the success function, **this** corresponds to the scope of the success function.

```
function Spotlight (mId,mName) {
    this.area = [];
    var scope = this;

    /**
     * Get all area information
     */
    this.getArea = function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: base_url +'spotlight/aGetArea',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                scope.area = data;
            }
        });
    }
}
```